# FadeOut and fadeIn not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new in the world of jQuery and have been fiddling around with my code to make it work, and so far no succes. The jQuery is not working and in the beginning I thought it was not directed  accordingly to the index.html file. So changed the file directory and changed the jQuery code many times. Still not working. 
The Css and HTML are working fine.

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Epic Forever :: Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="epic_home">
            <div id="eagleOne"></div>
            <div id="eagleTwo"></div>
        </section>

        <script src="assets/homepage.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#eagleOne, #eagleTwo {
    background: url('../images/homepage-eagle.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 60%;
    left: 32%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    width: 36%;}

#eagleOne, #eagleTwo{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */}

#eagleTwo{
    display: none;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */}
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#epic_home").on("mouseenter", "#eagleOne", function(){
    $("#eagleOne").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#eagleTwo").fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Whats the problem? It runs fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWLTj/).

Comment: @Hatsjoem, I know, but it is not working for me. 
What do you think it could be?

Comment: Have you added jQuery library?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question and show my full html here. just a moment.

Comment: o i think u missed this to add <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console (f12)?

Comment: Yes I added <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

How do I check for errors on a mac os?

Comment: cmd+opt+i to open console

Comment: Thank you @Hatsjoem !! I was saving the file but it wasn't uploading the file on the ftp, because I had moved it on the ftp. So I had to open it from the ftp and make the changes and save it. I was saving on a file that wasn't being saved.

Comment: No problem, glad you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the content in `#eagleOne, #eagleTwo` both div actually fade running but effect does not show untill you add the content or set the style that visualize the your both div, i have tried with

```
<section id="epic_home">
 <div id="eagleOne">data1</div>
 <div id="eagleTwo">data2</div>
</section>
```

just adding text in your both div

```
#eagleOne, #eagleTwo {
background: url('../images/homepage-eagle.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
display: block;
height: 60%;
left: 32%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 20%;
width: 36%;
border:1px solid #565656; /* for visualize your div */
}
```

see the js fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/N89Aq/

Comment: The content was in this case the .png file and didn't need text. But thanks anyway.  The issue here was, that I was saving a file that was not being saved, because the file had been moved. 
Gave you a point for it anyway ;)